# android how do i delete duplicate entry from database

Tags: android

Below is my code. I add application name in database and show that application in another screen but the problem is duplicate entry  will show  Main class help me plz. How do I remove duplicate entry from database.

```
public class SdcardAPkMgr extends ListActivity {
DatabaseHandler db;


       public Drawable getAPKDrawable(String filePath) {
    Drawable dr = null;
    if (filePath != null) {

        String PATH_PackageParser = "android.content.pm.PackageParser";
        String PATH_AssetManager = "android.content.res.AssetManager";
        try {
            Class pkgParserCls = Class.forName(PATH_PackageParser);
            Class[] typeArgs = new Class[1];
            typeArgs[0] = String.class;
            Constructor pkgParserCt = 
             pkgParserCls.getConstructor(typeArgs);
            Object[] valueArgs = new Object[1];
            valueArgs[0] = filePath;
            Object pkgParser = pkgParserCt.newInstance(valueArgs);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            metrics.setToDefaults();
            // PackageParser.Package mPkgInfo =
            // packageParser.parsePackage(new
            // File(apkPath), apkPath,
            // metrics, 0);
            typeArgs = new Class[4];
            typeArgs[0] = File.class;
            typeArgs[1] = String.class;
            typeArgs[2] = DisplayMetrics.class;
            typeArgs[3] = Integer.TYPE;
            Method pkgParser_parsePackageMtd = pkgParserCls
                    .getDeclaredMethod("parsePackage", 
                 typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[4];
            valueArgs[0] = new File(filePath);
            valueArgs[1] = filePath;
            valueArgs[2] = metrics;
            valueArgs[3] = 0;
            Object pkgParserPkg = pkgParser_parsePackageMtd.invoke(
                    pkgParser, valueArgs);
            Field appInfoFld = 
       pkgParserPkg.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "applicationInfo");
            ApplicationInfo info = (ApplicationInfo) appInfoFld 
              .get(pkgParserPkg);

            Class assetMagCls = Class.forName(PATH_AssetManager);
            Constructor assetMagCt = assetMagCls
                    .getConstructor((Class[]) null);
            Object assetMag = assetMagCt.newInstance((Object[]) null);
            typeArgs = new Class[1];
            typeArgs[0] = String.class;
            Method assetMag_addAssetPathMtd = assetMagCls
                    .getDeclaredMethod("addAssetPath", 
              typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[1];
            valueArgs[0] = filePath;
            assetMag_addAssetPathMtd.invoke(assetMag, valueArgs);
            Resources res = getResources();
            typeArgs = new Class[3];
            typeArgs[0] = assetMag.getClass();
            typeArgs[1] = res.getDisplayMetrics().getClass();
            typeArgs[2] = res.getConfiguration().getClass();
            Constructor resCt = 
            Resources.class.getConstructor(typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[3];
            valueArgs[0] = assetMag;
            valueArgs[1] = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            valueArgs[2] = res.getConfiguration();
            res = (Resources) resCt.newInstance(valueArgs);
            String label = null;
            if (info.labelRes != 0) {
                label = (String) res.getText(info.labelRes);
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addContact(new Contact(label));









                        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                OnItemClickListener {

   /* whether or not to include system apps */
   private static final boolean INCLUDE_SYSTEM_APPS = false;
   DatabaseHandler db;




                         private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
          List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

          // the package manager contains the information about all installed 
    apps
          PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

          List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); 
        //PackageManager.GET_META_DATA 





          for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
             PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
             ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = p.applicationInfo;
             String name = 
      packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo).toString();



             Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

                for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                    String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + 
      cn.getName() ;

                  //  String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + 
      cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                        // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.d("Name: ", log);



      //
             if ( ((name).contains(cn.getName())))
                     {
             App app = new App();

     app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
             app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
             app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
             app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
             CharSequence description = 
    p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(packageManager);
             app.setDescription(description != null ? description.toString() : 
        "");
             apps.add(app);
          }
          }}
          return apps;
       }







                         package com.gfsmart.filemanager;


import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
//private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
//  String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
//  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, 
   null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            //contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
//  values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

          }







                       public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;


// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;

}

// constructor
public Contact(String name){
    this._name = name;

}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}
```

Comment: MainActivity  class show duplicate  entry plz help me how do i remove

Comment: my code insert duplicates intry in my database every time i run application

Comment: you can prevent duplicate entries by using a unique constraint

Comment: If you want to stick to the application logic then you have to delete the duplicate records own your own... Try for deleting duplicate entries http://www.sqlteam.com/article/deleting-duplicate-records

OR Use **GroupBy** to Show only single istances of records

What I would suggest is to Debug your Application and look for why **addContact** is being called twice and prevent duplicate addition of records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you are inserting entry in database everytime at starting application. so just call below method before inserting entry into database. its for delete all the records from table.

Example:

```
db.deleteContact();
db.addContact(new Contact(label));
```

put below code in DatabaseHandler class:

```
 public int deleteContact() {
            try {
               SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                return db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: no i do not want to delete all record every time i want to just remove duplicate entry from database and show only singles record and save them

Comment: your table have all the entries duplicated. because you are inserting everytime on starting of application. you must have to delete all the records.

Comment: did not reconize   return db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);   db in DatabaseHelper class

Comment: w8 2 min dnt go anywhere ill check

Comment: ur code remove all previous record i want to just delete duplicate record  only

Comment: @SmartGuy why don't you prevent duplicate entries in the first place

Comment: @SmartGuy i suggested as per your code. if you want as per your requirements then first change your code as Raghunandan said..

Comment: my example code is this just tell me how do i remove duplicate entry
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141717/android-to-delete-duplicate-entry-from-table-when-inserting

Comment: when you create a table you can mention the unique constraint for the required column example  `KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL"+ " UNIQUE "`  this will make column with phonenumber unique and prevent duplicates.

Comment: this is corrrect check my code

String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME +  " TEXT NOT NULL"+ " UNIQUE `)";

Comment: your want the name unique or the phone number unique? some thing like  `String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL"+ " UNIQUE " + ");"`